# PDF viewer options for Firefox: passing the URL of the downloaded file?

Tags: firefox, pdf

Is there any way to invoke an (external) PDF viewer from Firefox such that the PDF viewer command-line contains not just the saved PDF file (/tmp/myfile.pdf) but **also** the URL that the PDF was downloaded from?

If I had this information, I could build a useful cache of PDFs ordered by the website they came from, for use when I was not connected to the internet.

Is there any open-source software that already achieves this? Or some some reconfiguration of the built-in PDF viewer in Firefox?

Comment: True -- with some kind of character encoding. But how would one automate the process that whenever clicking on a PDF, that Firefox runs that action?

Comment: I don't want to have to do the work of running the download... there can be files that are downloaded from password-controlled pages/sites. I was hoping to do this via a file-opening tool rather than a downloading tool...?